# VBA: Selecting range by variables

Tags: vba, variables, range, selection

I want to select the formatted range of an Excel sheet.
To define the last and first row I use the following functions:

```
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
```

In the next step I want to select this area:
Formula should look like this:

```
Range(cells(1, 1), cells(lastRow, lastColumn).Select
```

However, this is not working. Maybe somebody has an idea what is wrong with it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I tried filling up the range B2 to D4 with random data and your code selected A1 to D4. Isn't that what you'd expect?

Answer (score 53):

I recorded a macro with 'Relative References' and this is what I got :

```
Range("F10").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Range("A1:D11").Select
```

Heres what I thought : If the range selection is in quotes, VBA really wants a STRING and interprets the cells out of it so tried the following:

```
Dim MyRange as String
MyRange = "A1:D11"
Range(MyRange).Select
```

And it worked :) ie.. just create a string using your variables, make sure to dimension it as a STRING variables and Excel will read right off of it ;)

Following tested and found working :

```
Sub Macro04()

Dim Copyrange As String

Startrow = 1
Lastrow = 11
Copyrange = "A" & Startrow & ":D" & Lastrow
Range(Copyrange).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 16):

I ran into something similar - I wanted to create a range based on some variables.  Using the Worksheet.Cells did not work directly since I think the cell's values were passed to Range.

This did work though:

```
Range(Cells(1, 1).Address(), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn).Address()).Select
```

That took care of converting the cell's numerical location to what Range expects, which is the A1 format.

Comment: Thanks, I have spent all morning trying to figure out how to fix a syntax issue because of this. :)

Comment: Thank you you saved my day!

Comment: There's no need to use `.Address()` here.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to select the used range, use

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
```

If you want to select from A1 to the end of the used range, you can use the SpecialCells method like this

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Select
End With
```

Sometimes Excel gets confused on what is the last cell.  It's never a smaller range than the actual used range, but it can be bigger if some cells were deleted.  To avoid that, you can use Find and the asterisk wildcard to find the real last cell.

```
Dim rLastCell As Range

With Sheet1
    Set rLastCell = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart, , xlPrevious)

    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), rLastCell).Select
End With
```

Finally, make sure you're only selecting if you really need to.  Most of what you need to do in Excel VBA you can do directly to the Range rather than selecting it first.  Instead of

```
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), rLastCell).Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
```

You can

```
.Range(.Cells(1,1), rLastCells).Font.Bold = True
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a close parenthesis, I.E. you aren't closing `Range()`.

Try this `Range(cells(1, 1), cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Select`

But you should really look at the other answer from Dick Kusleika for possible alternatives that may serve you better. Specifically, `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select` which has the same end result as your code.

Answer (score 1):

you are turning them into an address but Cells(#,#) uses integer inputs not address inputs so just use `lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count` and `lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count`

Answer (score 1):

I tried using:

```
Range(cells(1, 1), cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Select
```

where `lastRow` and `lastColumn` are integers, but received run-time error 1004.  I'm using an older VB (6.5).

What did work was to use the following:

```
Range(Chr(64 + firstColumn) & firstRow & ":" & Chr(64 + lastColumn) & firstColumn).Select.
```

Comment: Actually firstColumn should read lastRow ==>    Range(Chr(64 + firstColumn) & firstRow & ":" & Chr(64 + lastColumn) & lastRow).Selec