# Sorting with VBA giving wrong result

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I have this code to sort an Excel sheet

```
'for the ascending order
Range("A14:CB" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range(Col & "14:" & Col & lastRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, key2:=Range("C14:C" & lastRow), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
'for the descending order
Range("A14:CB" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range(Col & "14:" & Col & lastRow), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo, key2:=Range("C14:C" & lastRow), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

This is what I get when I do ascending sort on `Col=J`

[image]

and this is what I get when I do descending sort on `Col=J`

[image]

Both are obviously wrong. Is there any error I am not seeing in the VBA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel's sort works quite well, e.g. select a range and run the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Selection.Sort key1:=Selection, Order1:=xlDescending

End Sub
```

In your code, you should check the variables, that define the range. E.g. `lastRow` and `Col`. Write something like this on the top of the code:

```
debug.print lastRow
debug.print Col
```

Comment: `lastRow` is 17 (data begins at 14) and`Col` is 10 (when selecting column J)

Comment: Then what do you expect from this thing here `Range(Col & "14:" & Col & lastRow)` E.g., if you go to the immediate window and you write `?Col & "14:" & Col & lastRow` what should it give you? I suppose that you have somewhere `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` has been removed, but still the issue is present. from the `Range(...)` I expect to act as `Range("J14:J17")`

Comment: Writing what you asked in the immediate window returns `1014:1017`

Comment: Then I suppose you can start fixing your error yourself. You should find a way to parse `Range(Col & "14:" & Col & lastRow)` to `Range("J14:J17")`. Here is how to start - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199318/vba-selecting-range-by-variables

Comment: `Range("A14:CE" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range(Cells(14, Col), Cells(lastRow, Col)), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, key2:=Range("C14:C" & lastRow), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo` indeed solved the issue