# copy sheet content to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy the content of one sheet at the end of the other, i have tried this vba code and it works,

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("B").Select
Range("A1:H14").Select
Range("A1:H14").Copy

Sheets("A").Select
' Find the last row of data
Range("B48:I48").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("A").Select
End Sub
```

but what i want is to copy without having to specify the range of the data, because i have many files and many data and it's gonna be hard to do all of that manually and change the range a each time.

Comment: Yes indeed, that would be  hard. Therefore VBA offers the concept of variables. Learn about them here. http://www.vbtutor.net/lesson6.html  or, perhaps, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199318/vba-selecting-range-by-variables

Comment: If you do not specify the cells, which cells should be copied? Do you want to copy all cells to the other sheet?

Comment: @ErdemAkkas yes i want to copy all cells to the other sheet, and if i don't specify the range, it give me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use so many `Select`, which slows down the code, you can use the 1 line below will copy the entire contents of `Sheet("B")` to the first empty row at Column "A" in `Sheet("A")`.

```
Dim Rng             As Range
Dim lRow            As Long
Dim lCol            As Long
Dim lPasteRow       As Long

With Sheets("B")

    lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

    lCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column

    lPasteRow = Sheets("A").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("A").Range("A" & lPasteRow + 1)
End With
```

Comment: this works like a charm, i have a question, what should i change to use a sheet from another file and copy it?

Comment: @zenami you refer to `Sheets("B")` ? or `Sheets("A")`?

Comment: i want to copy the content of sheet(1) from file1, to sheet(1) from file2, without overwriting the existent data

Comment: @zenami  I'll look at it later when I get home

Answer (score 4):

Below will copy entire content in `Sheet B` to `Sheet A`

```
Sheets("B").Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets("A").Range("A1")
```

You do not need to select cells while copying.

Comment: This actually overwites  the data that are in sheet(A)

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this, assuming sheet1 is the sheet to be updated by data from sheet2;

```
dim destLen as Long 'rows used in sheet 1
dim sourceLen as Long 'rows used in sheet 2
```

Open directory with source files and loop through each file and do the following

```
destLen = Sheet1.Range("A"&Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sourceLen = Sheet2.Range("A"&Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2.Range("B1" & ":I" & sourceLen).copy
Sheet1.Range("A" & destLen + 1).pasteSpecial xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: True, my mistake, I have corrected. The idea was primary to show how to obtain the last row. There are alternatives like usedrange but I have found it to be a bit unpredectable and the above has worked out for me thus far