# Count, insert row, paste in other tab

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a code that looks at column A in sheet1, then insert new lines in sheet2. Then paste the contents of column A (sheet1) into column A on sheet2. See attached pictures:
Sheet1 - total list
Sheet2 - existing list, need to add new lines from sheet1 and shift down the rest of contents.
Sheet3 - Result.

I do this manually every time but I am trying to make it automatic so I can save some time. I will assign a button to this.

Thanks in advance.
Nelson

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NwIf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ZOP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX3QK.jpg)

Comment: Do you have some sample code for us to look at that you attempted?  You could also look at this link for some ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468467/copy-sheet-content-to-another-sheet/43469300#43469300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code below :

```
Sub test()

            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Dim ws2 As Worksheet

            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
            Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            i = 1
            Do While ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value
                 i = i + 1
            Loop

            For j = i To lastRow
                lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                ws2.Rows(lastRow2 + 1).EntireRow.Insert
                ws2.Range("A" & lastRow2 + 1).Value = ws.Range("A" & j).Value
            Next j

        End Sub
```

Comment: `lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: You're right (y) ..

Comment: Thanks. But it pasted the values but I would like to insert entire rows so that everything below in sheet2 get push down and that way I don't loose formulas.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you .. do you mean the sheet2 is not empty ? and you want to add the values of column A in sheet1 to column A in sheet2 above the existing values ?

Comment: ok, so let me try to explain... I have a list of orders that increases every month so all I want to do is add the new ones but that is a section of sheet2 so I will like to add rows so I can push the bottom down instead of copying over.

Comment: Can I send you a file so you can see what I mean?

Comment: I edited my answer, check it and give me a feedback ..

Comment: This is close. is there a way we can have it to look at the latest order on sheet 2 and olnly add the new ones? for example, I have orders 1 thru 20 and now this month I have 1 thru 25, can I have it to just add 5 rows after the last one (20) and paste the new 5 values? Usually column A is only order numbers nothing else so it can look at the latest entry on sheet2.

Comment: So you need to add your entires at the end of sheet2 not at the top .. and you know your latest entry based on what ? the lastrow in sheet2 ? .. I need to see an example of what you want ..

Comment: can I send you and email with a file?

Comment: That is correct. I need to add entries at the end of sheet2, I would like it to compare to what I already have in sheet2 and add if there is new ones. sheet1 will always have the same or more than sheet2.

Comment: Hi, are you trying something? @LatifaShi ?

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't home .. check again my edited answer .. Hope it is what you are looking for this time ..

Comment: it brings the contents good but it doesnot insert rows for those new ones...it just past them below the last one

Comment: check my answer again I added a line : ws2.Rows(lastRow2 + 1).EntireRow.Insert

Comment: That's Perfect!!! Youre the best!!!!!! OMG you are going to save me hours of work!!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say Thank You...too excited!

Comment: I have another little request...can I bring the formulas from above to the new lines? starting in column B of sheet2?

Comment: You're welcome :). By the way, you could mark The answer as accepted for others by clicking the check mark next to the answer. For your other request  i'm sorry but I have never worked with formulas in excel so I'm not sure about How to manipulate them with VBA :p ..

Comment: No problem. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome ^^ ..