# Excel VBA range indexation

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a table which some particular content I want to copy into new Excel file. I have almost managed to achieve this. I have used following snippet for selection of data of my interest

```
Range(Range("A3"), Range("H3").End(xlDown))
```

This works fine for columns which have complete data. However, this does not work for columns which are mostly sparse. I am sure about last row of this column, which is `Range("H3").End(xlDown)` but I need somehow to increment `H` to `M` so the row index is same.

I looked in this topic [VBA: Selecting range by variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199318/vba-selecting-range-by-variables), nevertheless I was not able to utilize this solution (I am using VBA for one day).

Can you give me some advice about this, please?

I am not sure, if I have described my problem well. If it is not clear, I could try to do it better.

Comment: You can use a variable row like this: `Range("A" & lRow)`

Comment: You can use a variable row like this :Range(Cells(1, 1).Address(), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn).Address()).Select

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Comment: braX's solution works for me. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: This is a very common situation, already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920 (and in several other places!)  but `Range(Range("A3"), Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))` should work for you.